# How do I loop through structures within a structure? (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, object, structure

I'm trying to loop through structures' properties inside of one structure. It looks like this:

```
 Structure ObjectTypes

        Structure Object1
            Shared Property Name = "Object1"
            Shared Property Data = "Object1 Data"
        End Structure

        Structure Object2
            Shared Property Name = "Object2"
            Shared Property Data = "Object2 Data"
        End Structure

 End Structure
```

What I would like to do is loop through the objects' names inside the structure and see if it matches a value I give it, and if it does then use that object.

So something like this:

```
 For Each obj In ObjectTypes
      If obj.Name = "Object2" then
            'Do something with the object
      End if
 Next
```

Comment: Is that VB? you might get more useful response if you tag which language it is.

Comment: It looks like you just want one structure (or even a class) and multiple instances with different property values?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to accomplish that, I thought using structures was the easiest way to do that. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are your properties really named `Name` and `Data`? I suspect you want a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not a `Structure`. How about telling us [what you are trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/), not just what you are doing because what you are doing doesn't look right.

Comment: @DourHighArch I actually have multiple properties within each structure. I am trying to iterate between the objects declared in "ObjectTypes" and trying to check if a certain property ("Name" in this case) of each object within "ObjectTypes" is equal to a value I give. If it is, I'd like to use the rest of the object's properties later on. I think you're right, what I need is a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Dictionary` would allow you to fetch back a specific object by name.  It is not entirely clear this is appropriate here, but seems to be the case.

```
Public Class myThing
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Foo As String       
   Public Property Bar As Integer

   ' more code etc
End Class

Friend colThings As New Dictionary(Of String, myThing)

' add a thing to the dictionary
Dim item As New myThing
item.Name = "Ziggy"
item.Foo = "whatever"

colThings.Add(item.Name, item)
```

the collection now contains an object of type myThing, and uses the Name property as the key, so they must be unique, which is seems to be what the original code was trying to do in the loop.  To get ziggy back to use:

```
Dim tmpThing As myThing 
If colThings.ContainsKey("ziggy") Then
      tmpThing = colThings("ziggy")
End If
```

There are many useful methods with collections such as `.ContainsKey` to make the code readable and the collection easy to manage.  If the things are similar but not identical, you may want to look into inheritance, where similar types are defined from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by getting the `Type` of the most upper struct and get its nested types to match these against to your needs.

```
public static void Main()
{
    foreach(var _nestedType in typeof(ObjectTypes).GetNestedTypes())
    {
        if (_nestedType.Name = "Object1")
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}

public struct ObjectTypes
{
    public struct Object1
    {
        //..
    }

    public struct Object2
    {
        //..
    }
}
```